# How to ignore files and folders when publishing ASP.NET web app to Azure?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the built-in publishing tool outlined here to publish my ASP.NET web app to Azure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-get-started

How can I automatically ignore folders like wwwroot/lib, wwwroot/packages?

I have already tried these entries in .pubxml file without success

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    packages
  </ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you have created an ASP.NET 5 project. If so, you could modify the `publishOptions > exclude` section within your `project.json` file as follows:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/lib/**", //exclude all files/folders
    "wwwroot/lib/**/src/**" //exclude the files/folders under "src" folder
  ]
}
```

Additionally, ASP.NET recommends use [Bower](https://bower.io/) to manage client-side resources. And the JavaScript and CSS libraries are stored under `wwwroot\lib` by default. So, you could change the storage location for bower libraries to achieve your purpose. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx).

Comment: I found the answer shortly after posting :). Using jspm but thanks for the Bower stuff.